# Re $compile angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

OK I have a Meteor app that is using angular-meteor, I am using blaze to add a template into [autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) using textAngular which is just a simple angular directive,

Upon updating the form Meteor/Blaze/Autoform re renders the form programtically which in turn rips out the scope from my custom directive.

How do I rerender the angular 'textAngular' directive after Autoforms rerenders the form?

I'm assuming i should be using the `Template.NAME.rendered` event which works fine it calls after the rerender but how do I force angular to recompile the directive?

You can find the whole package [here](https://github.com/vimes1984/autoform-textangular) and my particular attempt at rerenderign [here](https://github.com/vimes1984/autoform-textangular/blob/master/lib/client/template.js)

Any help is greatly appriciated!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

OK I've done it like so :

```
Template.autoFormTextAngular.rendered = function () {
  if(!$(this.firstNode).hasClass('ta-root')){        
    // create an injector
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'textAngular']);
    // use the injector to kick off your application
    // use the type inference to auto inject arguments, or use implicit injection
    $injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile, $document) {
      $compile($document)($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$digest();
    });
  }
```

};

not sure if there is a easier way but hey ho it works...